# Problem while Debugging a C++ project using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, codeblocks

I'm having two errors everytime I try to debug a simple project in Visual Studio 2010.

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup   C:\Users\Fighter\Documents\C++\Point\Point\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)  Point

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Fighter\Documents\C++\Point\Debug\Point.exe    1   1   Point
```

this is a simple code I'm using to try my program in VS :

```
class Point

{
private:
int x;
int y;

};
```

The problem is that this thing works great in Code::Blocks but whith VS it gives me those errors.

What's the problem here.

Thanks

Comment: I've seen plenty of hate thrown at Code::Blocks but had no idea it was *this* bad.  What's the appeal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program needs a main() function to be valid.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    Point p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another problem is when I use an inline function with my class the debugger says : x is undefined?

Comment: @dotNET: that's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler says to you that he wants you to define an entry point to your application. (a.k.a a function main.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a function named `main()` or `main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Answer (score 0):

Every C++ program must have a function called `main()`.  It can take one of two forms:

1. `int main()`
2. `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`

Implement one of these (probably the first), and recompile.